# "Error starting Perl backend"

Tags: texmaker, perl, texlive-2019

I have Windows 10 and I am trying to install `texlive-full-2019` for TeXmaker. I `cd` into the directory containing the installation files for `texlive-full`. When I start `install-tl-windows.bat`, I get the following error:

```
Error starting Perl backend
Level 1: main_prog
Level 2: err_exit {Error starting Perl backend}
```

There is no `install-tl-advanced.bat` in the directory. I've already tried installing Strawberry Perl and ActiveState Perl (Perl TK; not simultaneously) to no avail. I still get the same error.

Can you help me?

Comment: It already comes with its own perl so no extra perl should be needed. Could you specify exactly what you did? And which version of the installer (if you downloaded the zip, which I recommend, and unpack it, then it creates a new folder which has a date stamp).

Comment: It is certainly a bug. I solved the problem by decompressing the archive, then in a command interpreter modify the PATH by: PATH = C: \ windows \ system32;% PATH% then launch the executable install-tl-windows.bat in the same command interpreter. (precede the full path)

Comment: Again on a normal windows installation system32 should already be in the PATH.

Comment: daleif: Thank you. That's the thing. When I installed texlive-full on my laptop, I had to install Perl. I was getting the same error and that fixed it. When I installed Perl on my laptop, the error went away. 
As for what I did on my desktop (the computer in question), I explained it in my question. In the command prompt, I cd-ed into the directory and called install-tl-windows.bat. It starts up then gives me the error.

gigiair and daleif: Thank you. system32 is already in the path.

Comment: Are there anymore tips? I still have this issue.